# nsis : NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin - minimize bug

Tags: nsis, nsis-plugin

anyone know how to resolve this bug with "NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin"
bug : When you click on min button, so the window still blocked, and only come back after 3-5 min.

basic example that i use :

Code :

```
Function .onInit
    ;User defined skin
    SetOutPath $TEMP
    File /oname=Robotics.skf "Robotics.skf"
    NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin::skin /NOUNLOAD $TEMP\Robotics.skf
    Delete $TEMP\Robotics.skf

    ;Default Skin
    ;NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin::skin /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sources for this plugin? Or is it some ind of 3rd party plugin?

Comment: NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin.dll - only compiled dll ,from  skincrafter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in "SkinBuilder"
clean_save_rebuild

[image]